# Change install location and prefix of homebrew packages

Tags: homebrew

My `/usr/local` and `/usr/local/bin` permissions on my machine are different from traditional machines (and they have to be that way).

Is it possible to configure homebrew to install in a different location `~/bin/` instead of `/usr/local/bin`?

I tried to change `HOMEBREW_PREFIX` environment variable, however I didn't see the change reflected when I ran `brew config`

So what I am asking is

1. Can I change my homebrew install location to my home directory
2. Can I change prefix of package install locations (packages installed by brew).

Answer (score 17):

1. It is possible to install homebrew into your home directory. I followed (more or less) the steps posted [here](http://lolindrath.com/2011/09/13/hombrew-from-home-directory/) and it succeeded. The exact commands I used:

   ```
   cd $HOME
   mkdir bin
   cd bin
   git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
   ```

   Then changed the assignment of the PATH variable in my bash profile.

   ```
   export PATH=${HOME}/bin/homebrew/bin:${PATH}
   ```

   However, this is specifically discouraged by Homebrew developers on their [installation documentation](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/Installation.md#installation). I can confirm that several packages worked (seqtk, pear) while others failed (wget, homebrew/science/blast, jags). I am also unable to change the ownership of my `/usr/local` directory, so I'm back to compiling those packages manually.
2. No, not to my knowledge. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31622073/brew-change-package-install-location).

Comment: This is my first answer; could someone explain why it might have been downvoted?

Comment: No, of course they can't, because that would actually be constructive.</sarcasm>